# Ajax: How to know if a user script implementation doesn't set the Origin header?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-headers, userscripts

Some user script implementations (like Google Chrome) allow direct cross AJAX requests, but some others don't, and use Same Origin Policy restrictions. Here's a part of code:

```
/*
 * Get the size of the file.
 * @Button the current button for downloading the video.
 * @Url the http url of the video.
 */
function SetFileSize(Button, Url) {
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onloadend = function () {
        GetResolution(Button, Url, ' - ' + (parseInt(this.getResponseHeader("Content-Length")) / 1048576).toFixed(3) + ' Mo')
    }
    ajax.open('HEAD', Url, true); // <-- HEAD allow to get only the data of the headers.
    ajax.send(null);
}

/*
 * Retrieve width and height from an MPEG-4 file.
 * Width and height are stored as float values, where width come next to height inside binary data.
 * There is no fixed place in the file. The method is to get them at 10 bytes before "mdia".
 */
function GetResolution(Button, Url, FileSize) {
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onloadend = function () {
        var metadata = new DataView(this.response);
        for (i = 0;(i < metadata.byteLength) && (metadata.getUint32(i) != 0x6D646961); i += 32) {} // 0x6D646961="mdia"
        button.setAttribute('title', metadata.getUint32(i - 14) + 'x' + metadata.getUint32(i - 10) + FileSize);
    }
    ajax.responseType = 'arraybuffer'; // We want to handle binary data.
    ajax.open('GET', Url, true); // <-- the 'false' have been deprecated.
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Range', 'bytes=181-300'); // Proceed with a partial download.
    ajax.send(null);
}
```

The result is the server *(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`)* sends a 400 error telling the`Origin`header is missing. Browsers doesn't allows to set the`Origin`header so a quick and dirty hack would be to set the custom`x-requested-with`. If an old browser set the`Origin`header correctly, this make a duplicate of`x-requested-with`. Here's would be code :

```
ajax.setRequestHeader('x-requested-with', document.domain); // chrome doesn't support setting the 'Origin' header automatically.
```

I can't use [try statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/en-uk/library/ie/4yahc5d8(v=vs.94).aspx) since synchronous AJAX requests got deprecated nor I can set the Origin header. So, How I can know if the browser doesn't set a particular header?

Comment: `x-requested-with` is never sent automatically. It is only added by popular libraries such as jQuery. When using XHR directly, *you* need to take care of adding the header. Also, people usually use a value of 'XMLHttpRequest' for the header and not the host.

Comment: @ThiefMaster : Yes I know this for `x-requested-with`. But the question is not about the fix. It is about the `Origin`header.

Comment: Could you show a complete demo? If I use `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://example.com` just works fine with this code.

Comment: @RobW : This is for a User Script designed to patch a site, so it is difficult to create a demo. It can't work with `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://example.com` since it require an MP4 URL. I can't [add an example URL](https://web.archive.org/web/20141008092627/http://floriancrouzat.net/arte/lawyered.html) of the site publicly.

Comment: User scripts already have cross-origin access... That's why the Origin header does not show up. Try without cors-anywhere and see whether the request succeeds.

Comment: @RobW : Yes, but some browsers apply SOP in that case, and refuse to return the result. That's why I'm using a CORS proxy.

Comment: @user2284570 Every major browser that supports user scripts also supports cross-origin requests. If you really need to dynamically detect whether CORS is needed, send a request to `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/iscorsneeded`. If the request fails, then CORS is needed and you can use the CORS proxy. If the request succeeds, then CORS is not needed, and you can directly request the URL.