# Why can I not return responseText from an Ajax function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, return, alert, responsetext

Here is part of my Ajax function. For some reason that I cannot figure out, I am able to *alert()* responseText but not able to *return* responseText. Can anybody help? I need that value to be used in another function.

```
http.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if( http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200 ){
        return http.responseText;
    }
}
```

Comment: See [
how to return variable from the function called by onreadystatechange=function()
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955248/how-to-return-variable-from-the-function-called-by-onreadystatechangefunction) and [
In AJAX how to retrive variable from inside of onreadystatechange = function ()
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290214/in-ajax-how-to-retrive-variable-from-inside-of-onreadystatechange-function).

Answer (score 5):

You will not be able to handle the return value that you are returning from your asynchronous callback. You should handle the `responseText` within the callback directly, or call a helper function to handle the response:

```
http.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        handleResponse(http.responseText);
    }
}

function handleResponse (response) {
    alert(response);
}
```

Comment: You can also have the function that sets `http.onreadystatechange` take a callback parameter, and call that.  See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290214/in-ajax-how-to-retrive-variable-from-inside-of-onreadystatechange-function/290288#290288).

Comment: @Matthew: Yes, that's a neat idea :)

Comment: But alert is not the same as return you can alert from within the onreadystatechange, But if you do inside handleResponse `return response` it doesnt return the value to the initial function call.

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
function handleResponse (response) {
    return response;
}
```

which return undefined for synchrounous and asynchronous modes

Comment: and how does this relate to the question ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getdata(url,callback)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
         var result = xmlhttp.responseText;
         callback(result)
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

send a call back function name as second arguement to this function.
You can get the response text for that function. simple. But you can't directly return anything from an asynchronous call.