# Need the responseText of jQuery.ajax returned instead of using the 'success' function

Tags: jquery, ajax, responsetext

I would like to have a function that *returns* the repsonseText of a jQuery.ajax() call. All the examples I've seen say to use a 'success' function to handle the returned data. However, for my implementation I need something like following:

```
function getRemoteValue(id) {
  var request = jQuery.ajax({
    url:'somefile.php',
    dataType:'text'
  });
  return request.responseText;
}
```

When I make a call to this function, Firebug shows the request as going through with the correct Response being returned. However when I try the following, I only get an empty string:

```
var some_value = getRemoteValue(1); // The problem is here. some_value is empty.
jQuery('.someclass').html(some_value);
// Other processing using some_value;
```

Again, for my implementation I can't be doing the jQuery('.someclass').html(some_value); within the ajax() call. How can I get the responseText returned? Thank you!

Comment: I'd check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732258/why-can-i-not-return-responsetext-from-an-ajax-function

Comment: Thanks for the link. The whole "asynchronous" wasn't sinking in at first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rober ,

The following code is valid but returns null

```
var some_value = getRemoteValue(1);
```

The ajax call is asyncronous call , it just instantiates the process goes on , so you will always have this problem

You need to move your code to your success handler of ajax to do any post operations.