# Returning a result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a JavaScript function that posts to a php, and returns the value, so that calling the function from another function in JavaScript gives me the value. To illustrate better please look at my current code:

```
function sumValues(number1, number2) {
    var return_val;
    $.post("sum_values.php", {number1: number1, number2: number2},
    function(result) {
        return_val = result;
    });

    return return_val;
}
```

However, the above is returning undefined. If I put `alert(result)` inside the *function* part in `$.post`, I can see the result. However if I call the function from another JavaScript file the return value return_val is 'undefined'. How can I put the result from `$.post` inside `return_val` so that the function can return it?

Comment: You can't, you need to provide a callback. This is asynchronous. This is a duplicate, I just need a few seconds to find a question.

Comment: Other almost identical questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732258/why-can-i-not-return-responsetext-from-an-ajax-function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290214/in-ajax-how-to-retrive-variable-from-inside-of-onreadystatechange-function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955248/how-to-return-variable-from-the-function-called-by-onreadystatechange-function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562412/return-value-from-function-with-an-ajax-call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronous meaning that by the time your function returns results might not have yet arrived. You can only use the results in the `success` callback. It doesn't make sense to have a javascript performing an AJAX request to return values based on the results of this AJAX call.

If you need to exploit the results simply invoke some other function in the `success` callback:

```
function sumValues(number1, number2) {
    $.post("sum_values.php", { number1: number1, number2: number2 },
    function(result) {
        callSomeOtherFunction(result);
    });
}
```

and inside the `callSomeOtherFunction` you could show the results somewhere in the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

$.post is asynchronous by default ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)). You could either pass the `async:false` option (blocks the browser, not a good user experience) or you should consider using callback functions (better IMHO).

```
function sumValues(number1, number2,callback) {
$.post("sum_values.php", {number1: number1, number2: number2},callback);
}

sumValues(1,3,function(result){ 
    doSomething(result); 
});
```